# How can I still play Flash games/animations after Flash's death?

Tags: windows, windows-10, flash-player

There's a lot of good animations and games on Newgrounds and many other sites. They all used touse Flash player, too. Unfortunately, Flash has been discontinued on the last day of 2020. However, the Newgrounds player that replaced Flash player on Newgrounds apparently doesn't work on all games because they haven't been converted from Flash yet. Also, other sites still haven't got the message and still use Flash.

Any ideas on any workarounds to still access these games/animations? If anybody has asked this question before, please link me to the dupe.

By the way, I am using Windows 10 and I either use FireFox or Chrome as my main browsers, so any solutions using them would be preferred.

RIP Flash

Comment: What OS?............

Comment: @Moab Edited it in, is that good?

Comment: Have you tried googling this?  There are plenty of resources out there

Comment: @Keltari what do you suggest I google? "How to play flash games"?

Comment: Read this:  https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14418/what-should-we-do-with-flash-shockwave-questions

Comment: @SomeGuy What do I suggest?  Google the question you want answered.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it is called BlueMaxima Flashpoint, and it archives a ton of games and animations. In fact, the smaller download, which is only 2 gigabytes, has all my favorite games there.